# Javascript variables scope and use in JQuery

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have very little knowledge of javascript and jquery, but I was able to put the following code together.

I want to add the result of 'name' to the div "displayName" on an html page when I click the "nameCreationButton" button on the html page.  When I click "nameCreationButton", absolutely nothing happens.

I declared the variable 'name' outside of the function 'generator', so my jquery should be able to access it, right?  I have spent hours looking at this, and I feel silly for not understanding why it will not work.

```
function generator(){

  var firstName = ["John","Mike","Robert","Patrick"];
  var lastName = ["Smith","Johnson","Williams","Anderson"];

  var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * firstName.length);
  var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * lastName.length);
  var name = firstName[randomNumber1] + " " + lastName[randomNumber2];
}

var name;

generator();

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nameCreationButton").click(function(){
    $(".displayName").append('name');
 });
});
```

Here is my HTML page if it is any use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script type= 'text/javascript' src='nameGenerator_JS.js'></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
    <button class = "nameCreationButton">Click Here to Generate Name</button>
    <div class = "displayName"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `'` quote?

Comment: Also, there is nothing like JavaScript variable and jQuery variable...

Comment: Remove the spaces in your html as well. Should be `class="nameCreationButton"`

Comment: And you should use `.text()`

Comment: @Mr.Alien, it's allowed, but reduces readability and no one does it like that. Especially since he isn't consistent in one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no point in declaring the variable `name` twice. You do it once inside `generator()` and once as a global which is not a very good idea.

Instead, what you want is to execute the function `generator()` once you click on the button. This function needs to return the `name`.

To rewrite this:

```
function generator(){
    var firstName = ["John","Mike","Robert","Patrick"],
        lastName = ["Smith","Johnson","Williams","Anderson"],
        randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * firstName.length, 10),
        randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * lastName.length, 10);

    return firstName[randomNumber1] + " " + lastName[randomNumber2];
}

$(function(){
    $(".nameCreationButton").click(function(){
        //var name = generator();
        $(".displayName").append(generator());
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/2pq2Z/)

Comment: This is the best answer. :) Not limited to the question and it's improving the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the single `'` quote on `append('name')`.

And also you need to remove the `var` declaration for the `name` variable inside the `generator` `function`. The `var name` inside the `generator` block ({ ...}) makes the variable only visible inside that block. So on your original code, you are having two different variables named `name` with two different scopes.

Try:

```
function nameGenerator(){

  var firstName = ["John","Mike","Robert","Patrick"];
  var lastName = ["Smith","Johnson","Williams","Anderson"];

  var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * firstName.length);
  var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * lastName.length);
  return firstName[randomNumber1] + " " + lastName[randomNumber2];
}


$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".nameCreationButton").click(function(){
    var name = nameGenerator();
    $(".displayName").text(name);
 });
});
```

Comment: or `return name` from the generator would be cleaner

Answer (score 2):

(*) you had rfered variable with quotes, it will be considered a string

```
 var name = "aslan";
 console.log(name) //=> aslan
 console.log("name") //=> name
```

(*) also, variable name is declared inside and out side function.
    variable declared inside function is considered as local variable, 
    so var name declared outside function wont get update, which us used append().
    check : http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

**Change code to:**

```
 function generator(){

   var firstName = ["John","Mike","Robert","Patrick"];
   var lastName = ["Smith","Johnson","Williams","Anderson"];

   var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * firstName.length);
   var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * lastName.length);
   return  firstName[randomNumber1] + " " + lastName[randomNumber2];
 }


 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nameCreationButton").click(function(){
      $(".displayName").append( generator() );
   });
 });
```